# The default case always run in menu switch

Tags: java, switch-statement

Why the default case always run?

```
public class HelloWorld {
    public enum ScenarioState {
        INIT,
        START,
        STOP,
        DESTROY
    }

    public static void displayRecord(ScenarioState state) {
        switch (state) {
            case INIT:
            case START:
            case STOP:
                System.out.println("1");
            default:
                System.out.println("default");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScenarioState state = ScenarioState.INIT;
        displayRecord(state);
    }
}
```

The expected output should be

> 1

but the actual Output:

> 1
>   default

Why cause this problem? anyone can help me

Comment: did you forget `break;` statement ?

Comment: You are missing `break;` statements .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a `break` to all your switch-branches or you will experience what you are experiencing right now, called a *fall-through*.

Java will execute all statements starting from your matching case sequentially until it encounters the end of the switch or a break-statement.

In your case it seems actually want that fall-through for all your branches other than the default branch. So you would need to add a break at the end of your `STOP` case.

This would be the correct way to go:

```
switch (state)
{
    case INIT:
    case START:
    case STOP:
        System.out.println("1");
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("default");
}
```

Comment: Could I ask why this is getting a downvote? Did I miss something?

Comment: Don't know, I was reading this question and thought that this answer was the most complete. Maybe due to answer a surely duplicated and low quality question? Anyway, this answer is the best of three and solves the question's author. Voted up

Comment: Some people probably think this simple problem should be a comment and not an answer. At least that's been my experience. But I disagree with that ;)

Comment: Thought same, but why the other answers doesn't has a down vote?

Comment: I downvoted, because the OP clearly expects `1` to be print out when switching on `INIT`. Which your answer doesn't allow anymore

Comment: Ah thanks for pointing that out. But why not just point it out to.. improve the answer? Well, I could improve the answer now, so still thanks a lot!

Comment: make an edit, an the downvote will be withdrawn. Because currently your answer is just *wrong* and missleading

Comment: I already did ;)

Answer (score 2):

Add the `break;` statement to After your *Case*

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `break;` to the end of each case statement.